# Can I set Tomcat with a welcome-file in a subfolder?

Tags: configuration, tomcat6, web.xml

Someone at the office threw me this weird-yet-interesting question.

If I have something like this in a web.xml (either app' file or container's file)

```
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>something.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

and the thing has another page in a subfolder that can be used so I change it...

```
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>subfolder/something.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

¿Should the second option work? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering to myself just to let it in the record.

**Yes**, it can be done. The address bar shows the context URL without the subfolder specified in the welcome-file directive. But it works fine.