# welcome-file does not work in WebLogic

Tags: spring, weblogic

When I deploy my web application (Spring MVC) on WebLogic, the welcome page does not launch with the default URL http://my.site.com/myApp. I have my welcome page under home directory and I set as follows in web.xml.

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/home/index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

I am able to access the page using the full URL http://my.site.com/myApp/home/index.html.

Also, if I put index.html directly under the root and update web.xml as follows, the welcome page launches with the default URL

```
<welcome-file>/index.html</welcome-file>
```

What should I do to make the default URL launch the index.html under home directory ?

Here is the code in web.xml and applicationContext.xml.

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
  <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
```

Comment: Are you sure this is not a problem related to Spring MVC's Web Filter?

Answer (score 0):

I assume it has something to do with the leading slash. Have you tried simply `home/index.html` instead of `/home/index.html`.

This user asked the same question but had it work without the initial slash: [can-i-set-tomcat-with-a-welcome-file-in-a-subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620063/can-i-set-tomcat-with-a-welcome-file-in-a-subfolder)

[Another discussion on the same topic:](http://www.coderanch.com/t/606329/Tomcat/jsp-page-subdirectory-served-page)

Comment: I tried home/index.html instead of /home/index.html. It did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue.

> Make sure that the file you are trying to show is outside the
>   **web-inf** folder.

There are some configurations available in weblogic.xml file but none seems to work.I think it's a security feature or something else not sure exactly what.

In my case dispatcher servlet was capturing the empty request and showing no mapping found. May be you can create a controller mapping for the same and be done with it.

The funny thing is the same thing was working flawlessly in tomcat 7

Comment: Welcome to SO, This is not a forum where we just contribute to a thread. Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer on how to write an answer.